# Kinect microphone not working

Tags: kinect, xbox, kinect-sdk

I have been working on kinect for like 2 moths.I just upgraded from sdk 1.5 to sdk 1.6. Everything is working fine except for the microphone.When ever I launch an audio application from tool-kit it says my kinect audio not found.I Have installed the same SDK on another pc and everything is working fine on it.I have kinect for xbox. The audio drivers are installed correctly because its showing "Kinect for windows audio array control" in device manager under Microsoft kinect and also "Kinect USB Audio" under sound,video and game controllers. I had removed all previous versions of sdk and drivers before installing the new one.Please help me figure this out

edit:I even installed the previous 1.5 version but still the microphone is not working.Is there any software that is blocking it or any settings I have to check?

Answer (score 1):

Very strange behaviour, the only problem i know with the Audio of Kinect is that the audio stream is stopped after the skeleton stream is enabled.

The problem is not with your sensor, since you instaled it in another computer and it worked.

Try to uninstall everything again, even the speech recognition SDK (if instaled). Delete the related folders from ProgramFiles, reboot and try to install it again.

you could also check the following:

- Check if is possible to use another microphone.
- Check the messages in the `Windows Events` of your control panel.